# What is a dehydrated detector and how am I using one here?

Tags: angular

I'm using a simple directive to focus a text input when the element is active using `*ngIf`. This is contained within a `*ngFor` loop.

When the first `*ngIf` is activated, the input focuses as expected. When another input is activated I get the error:

`EXCEPTION: Attempt to use a dehydrated detector.`

I don't understand what this means and how I can prevent the error. The functionality still works even with the error.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[myAutoFocus]'
})
export class AutoFocusDirective {
    constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            elem.nativeElement.querySelector('input').focus();
        });
    }
}
```

```

Comment: I have this error, I solved maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952068/angular2-exception-attempt-to-detect-changes-on-a-dehydrated-detector

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Dehydrated detector** is a component that has been removed from the change detection system, usually because it has been unmounted from DOM by `*ngIf` or other [means](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e7ad03cba6696fac4eed282ecccd5eb85a36ddb6/modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/abstract_change_detector.ts#L167%0A): 
If there's an asynchronous action in the application that hits this already unmounted detector, error is [thrown](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e7ad03cba6696fac4eed282ecccd5eb85a36ddb6/modules/angular2/test/core/change_detection/change_detector_spec.ts#L1181%0A):
solution is to use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf` on the affected component, or defer the offending action to next tick using `setTimeout( () => this.offendingAction(), 0)`

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Spend hours trying to fix this. 
setTimeout( () => this.offendingAction(), 0) works perfect

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue on GitHub for this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786#issuecomment-185429140

In beta.2, no exception was thrown. In beta.3-6 (4,5, and 6 seem to be just increments with no changes), the code was changed to throw an exception. You are correct that this currently does not pose an issue.

While I do not know the exact reason you receive this error, one of my accounts with it came from disposing of a component during the angular check cycle, where it updates views.  Others have logged their issues on the github thread.

Answer (score 0):

A "dehydrated detector" means that the change detector for that component/directive is no longer hydrated.  (Sorry, I just couldn't resist -- I have no idea what this error means either, nor do I know what "hydrated" or "dehydrated" is supposed to convey.)

This [source file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e7ad03cba6696fac4eed282ecccd5eb85a36ddb6/modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/exceptions.ts#L89) says:

```
/**
 * Thrown when change detector executes on dehydrated view.
 *
 * This error indicates a bug in the framework.
 *
 * This is an internal Angular error.
 */
export class DehydratedException extends BaseException {
  constructor(details: string) { super(`Attempt to use a dehydrated detector: ${details}`); }
}
```

So you probably found an internal Angular bug.

I can't reproduce your error with this [simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AWEjGzMPqRAa9o71y3es?p=preview).  Do you have a plunker that shows the issue?

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786

Comment: I couldn't seem to reproduce the error in Plunker. I'm using Ionic 2, so I assume it's something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exception before and it very much means that you are using something that is no longer exists in the virtual memory. In my case, I was doing almost the same what you were doing. Notice you are trying to access an element after a timeout, but are you sure this element exists in the memory after this time is elapsed? I have *ngIf on that element and I accessed after the condition was false and it was already removed.