# Angular2 EXCEPTION: Attempt to detect changes on a dehydrated detector

Tags: angular

I am having this error `EXCEPTION: Attempt to detect changes on a dehydrated detector.` and after reading a few online pages. I have not very clear how to fix it or because it is.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e7ad03cba6696fac4eed282ecccd5eb85a36ddb6/modules/angular2/src/core/change_detection/exceptions.ts#L87

The error begins in my case when I put some components while using `@RouteConfig RouterLink`

and one of my components use this constructor

```
constructor(http: Http, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {
            ..//
            setInterval(() => {
              this.ref.detectChanges();
            }, 5000);
```

if I comment and change the constructor something like this error disappears

```
constructor(http: Http) {
                ..//
                /*
                   setInterval(() => {
                     this.ref.detectChanges();
                   }, 5000);
                */
```

someone to be this, or any alternative to solve it using `ChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786

Comment: @EricMartinez Thank you for your comment. I solved it.

Answer (score 3):

After reading the commentary Eric Martinez. I solved in my case using `OnDestroy` and `detach()` in the tests I've done it seems to work well hope it helps others.

```
    import {Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnDestroy} from "angular2/core";
    ..//

    export class Test implements OnDestroy{
    ..//

    constructor(http: Http, public ref: ChangeDetectorRef){
    ..//

            setInterval(() => {
              this.ref.detectChanges();
            }, 5000);

    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
      this.ref.detach();
    }
```

NOTE: I'm new to Angular2 and do not know if this really is the best solution

Comment: While that issue isn't solved by ng2 team, every workaround will work. It's not a definitive solution.

Comment: this looks like a "hack" rather than a solution, especially since the interval is never cleared and creating and destroying the component leaves intervals that forever call `this.ref.detectChanges` on a detached change detector.

Answer (score 0):

Implement the `OnDestroy` in your component class by importing as below

```
import { Component, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
```

**Then do as below**

```
ngAfterViewInit() { // *Bind when component loads
    console.log('onLoad');
    this.zone.reattach();
}

detectChanges(val: any){ // * Runs outside Angular Code
  /*Your codes and logic*/
  this.intrv = setInterval(()=>{
    this.zone.detectChanges();
  }, 1000)
}

ngOnDestroy() { // * Clean after leave. Clear any intervals or setTimeouts here.
   this.zone.detach();
   if(this.intrv){ //Making sure everything is removed
     clearInterval(this.intrv);
   }
}
```

***Read the code comments for explaination.*** Above code saved me from the errors.

---

**Explaination:**

- Bind to the *change detector* API on intialization using `ngAfterViewInit()`
- Listen to the Code outside angular and apply changes to the *Model*
- When you move out of the view. detach the *change Detector* using `ngOnDestroy()`

---

**Documentation:**

- https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detach-anchor
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Example