# Angular2 - Uncaught Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

So my application keeps giving me this error:

```
extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8 Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
at ViewDestroyedException.BaseException [as constructor] (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:3776:27)
at new ViewDestroyedException (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:6957:20)
at DebugAppView.AppView.throwDestroyedError (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:10041:76)
at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:9994:22)
at DebugAppView.detectChanges (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:10084:48)
at ViewRef_.detectChanges (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/@angular/core/core.umd.js:9397:69)
at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/scripts/components/product-card.component.js:63:54)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/rxjs/Subject/../bundles/Rx.umd.js:1408:16)
at SafeSubscriber.next (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/rxjs/Subject/../bundles/Rx.umd.js:1357:22)
at Subscriber._next (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/rxjs/Subject/../bundles/Rx.umd.js:1307:26)
at Subscriber.next (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/rxjs/Subject/../bundles/Rx.umd.js:1271:18)
at Subject._finalNext (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/rxjs/Subject/../bundles/Rx.umd.js:1063:30)
at Subject._next (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/rxjs/Subject/../bundles/Rx.umd.js:1055:18)
at Subject.next (chrome-extension://npblbblmbmcjbldhcneoocaobkkicbno/node_modules/rxjs/Subject/../bundles/Rx.umd.js:1012:14)handler @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8(anonymous function) @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:100EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:376EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:393target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94messageListener @ extensions::messaging:189target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19EventImpl.dispatchToListener @ extensions::event_bindings:387target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:371EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:393target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94dispatchOnMessage @ extensions::messaging:320
```

Upon calling detectChanges on a component's ChangeDetectorReference: `this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();`

I came across a similar stack over question:

[What is a dehydrated detector and how am I using one here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35515254/what-is-a-dehydrated-detector-and-how-am-i-using-one-here)

and some github issues:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6786#issuecomment-185429140

That led me to call detectChanges as such:

`setTimeout( () => this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(), 10);`

Which changed the error to this:

```
zone.js:260 Uncaught Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:260
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
```

But it is still happening.  It is not breaking my application (it was before using setTimeout), but I would like to figure out how to get rid of it.

I'm calling detectChanges() because there are things happening in the background that change the state of the application (not the result of user input).  The component is not newly created or about to be destroyed when detectChanges() is called. The component's style changes as a result of something that happens in the background.

Comment: "Which changed the error, but it is still happening" -- what does that mean?  Are you getting a different error?  You also need to give us some more details.  When are you calling detectChanges()?  Why dare you calling it?  Is the component newly created or about to be destroyed when you call it?

Comment: Hey @MarkRajcok, I've update the question with more details and clarified.

Comment: Where do you call `detectChanges()`?

Answer (score 5):

In the constructor of your class to give:

```
setTimeout( () => this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck(), 10);
```

And in @component:

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

Comment: And this will do what exactly? This is not a very detailed answer.

Comment: the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush will switch from Default to OnPush change detection for the component. It means that the component will notify inner changes only when new variables references are pushed to it, but mutability will no longer trigger changes. 
For instance, with OnPush strategy, if you do `[componentState]="myVariable"` and in your parent component or view, you change myVariable like `myVariable.push(new Item())` it will no longer detect the change. You'll have to do `myVariable = [...myVariable, newItem];`

Answer (score 2):

My errors were being thrown because of a `subscribe()` trying to execute its completion code after the view had already changed.

```
...
.then(response => {
    ...
    scope.cdr.detectChanges();
});
...
```

This would happen if I switched the view very quickly or the internet was slow.

---

I created a boolean when the view is created and set to true:

```
view_active: Boolean = true
```

then when the view is destroyed set it to false:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.view_active = false
}
```

and then check against that before calling `detectChanges()`

```
...
.then(response => {
    ...
    if(scope.view_active) {
        scope.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
});
...
```

Comment: not elegant but this is the only answer that's worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use this:

```js
import { ChangeDetectorRef, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';

setTimeout(() => {
  if(!(this.changeDetectorRef as ViewRef).destroyed) {
    this._changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
}, 10);
```